# Retrieving all contact id with length 4 android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I need to retrieve contacts Id with that have <=7 characters and add two 0's in front and update the contact list. How can i achieve this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int PICK_CONTACT    = 1;
    Uri uri;
    TextView txt_contacts;
    Cursor c = null;
    MainActivity context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context=this;


        getContactList();


        // this opens the activity. note the  Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        // and the intent.setType
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_contacts)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // user BoD suggests using Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of .ACTION_GET_CONTENT to avoid the chooser
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);  
                txt_contacts =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_contacts);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();

            if (uri != null) {

                try {
                    c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID },
                            null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String number = c.getString(0);
                        int type = c.getInt(1);
                        showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {

        String new_num = 0+number;


        /*
         * QUERY TO UPDATE PHONE NUMBER
         */


        ContentValues _changed_values=new ContentValues();
        _changed_values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,new_num);
        getContentResolver().update(uri,_changed_values,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID+"=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(type)});

        txt_contacts.setText(new_num);

    }


    public List<Person> getContactList(){
        ArrayList<Person> contactList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        };

        String SELECTION = "LENGTH(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + ")>'7'";
        Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);

        if (contacts.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while(contacts.moveToNext()) {
                Person aContact = new Person();
                int idFieldColumnIndex = 0;
                int nameFieldColumnIndex = 0;
                int numberFieldColumnIndex = 0;

                String contactId = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                nameFieldColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
                if (nameFieldColumnIndex > -1)
                {
                    aContact.setName(contacts.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex));
                }

                PROJECTION = new String[] {Phone.NUMBER};
                final Cursor phone = managedQuery(Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
                if(phone.moveToFirst()) {
                    while(!phone.isAfterLast())
                    {
                        numberFieldColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                        if (numberFieldColumnIndex > -1)
                        {
                            aContact.setPhoneNum(phone.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex));
                            phone.moveToNext();
                            TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
                            mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                            if (!mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number().contains(aContact.getPhoneNum()))
                            {
                                contactList.add(aContact);  
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                phone.close();
            }

            contacts.close();
        }

        return contactList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this: 
[How to get contacts from native phonebook in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253029/how-to-get-contacts-from-native-phonebook-in-android)

For your case you should just have to change the SELECTION query statement to something like:

```
Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
};
String SELECTION = "LENGTH(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + ")<='4'";
Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);
```

Comment: um, why would you use the answer, update the question And downvote?

Comment: i did not downvote. Your answer was good why should i do this